# Editor jQuery TE getting an empty field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, editor, fckeditor

Who have worked with this editor, can know how to solve the issue with **copy / insert** in the textarea field, *framed* by this editor?

When copying and pasting text from outside (copy the text on any web site) - after being sent to the server, the field is coming **blank**. If you enter text by hand - on the server obtains the **full** text.

Link to the Editor: http://jqueryte.com/

May be you can advise me the better editor?